# Maximum possible angular scopes for a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Angular uses 3 alpha numeric characters for scope id. For example 002,0FG,AAA...

Does that mean that there is a limit to 46656 unique scopes for a page? Does angular increase the number of characters in the scope id if that limit is reached, or what will happen to that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in the source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a591e8b8d302efefd67bf0d5c4bad300a5f3aded/src/Angular.js#L296

```
/**
 * A consistent way of creating unique IDs in angular.
 *
 * Using simple numbers allows us to generate 28.6 million unique ids per second for 10 years before
 * we hit number precision issues in JavaScript.
 *
 * Math.pow(2,53) / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365 / 10 = 28.6M
 *
 * @returns {number} an unique alpha-numeric string
 */
function nextUid() {
  return ++uid;
}
```

generate 28.6 million unique ids per second for 10 years... so 9.0252734e+15

that nextUid is referenced here when creating scopes: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7c6026437afe2ea4bdf824cbe022d4849264bb70/src/ng/rootScope.js#L208

Comment: Looks like they changed the scope.$id to be just a number, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7c6026437afe2ea4bdf824cbe022d4849264bb70/docs/content/guide/migration.ngdoc#L99

Comment: I thought it was weird where it said `@returns {number} an unique alpha-numeric string`, but it looks like it was just a leftover from the previous version and they just changed `{string}` to `{number}` and left the description.

Comment: The commit changing $id to be numeric is there: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/8c6a8171f9bdaa5cdabc0cc3f7d3ce10af7b434d